# how to grab data from this type of json response?

Tags: go

when parsing after a get request, how would I grab the 'personaname' and 'realname' values? the way I'm doing it with this struct

```
type Response struct {
    personaname string
    realname string
}
```

and this code

```
sb := string(res.Body())
var response []Response
json.Unmarshal([]byte(sb), &response)
```

isn't giving me anything. any tips? I'm not really familiar with json and how this kind of json works. (below is the response json)

```
{
  "response": {
    "players": [
      {
        "personaname": "alfred",
        "realname": "alfred d"
      },
      {
        "personaname": "EJ",
        "realname": "Erik Johnson"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: even if i do that it still outputs nothing

Comment: json.Unmarshal gives me no error, and it still outputs nothing. I've done what you told me.

Answer (score 3):

You need to define a full structure that matches the JSON, partially or totally but from the root.

https://play.golang.org/p/I8fUhN4_NDa

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Body struct {
    Response struct {
        Players []Player
    }
}

type Player struct {
    PersonaName string
    Realname    string
}

func main() {

    body := []byte(`{
          "response": {
            "players": [
              {
                "personaname": "alfred",
                "realname": "alfred d"
              },
              {
                "personaname": "EJ",
                "realname": "Erik Johnson"
              }
            ]
          }
        }`)

    var parsed Body
    if err := json.Unmarshal(boddy, &parsed); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%+v", parsed.Response.Players)

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually your structure won't work since you body request is an array of objects.
With this structure you wait for body like this`{ "personaname": "alfred", "realname": "alfred d"}` with just one object.

I recommend you to create a new structure that takes a slice pointing to your structure response.
You would have like

```
   type Response struct {
    Personaname string
    Realname string
   }
    
    type Rsp struct {

        Players []Response `json:"players"`
    }
```

Comment: this sadly doesnt fix the issue.

Comment: var a Resp
err := json.NewDecoder(res.Body).Decode(&a)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }
 fmt.Println(a.Players.Personaname)

Can your try that ?

Comment: I actually edited the post with capital letters

Comment: ive found a solution already. thank you tho